# Adding "new" tags

Tags: feature-request, new-users, tag-creation

I support the idea of only allowing new tags to be created if you have so much rep. The problem I ran into on mathematics and some other stackexchanges is that when it's new or not as busy you have issues of having to incorrectly tagging things because your tag isn't created yet.

I am not sure if there is a request that gets logged when new users try a tag and its denied, but there should be. After so many users try a tag thats not created the system should auto-create it and not wait for someone else to do so.

Comment: There actually has been a past request of this sort. I'm not sure if it's a full-fledged question of its own, and I'll look for it, but the idea has definitely been passed around in the past.

Comment: The standard workaround, I believe, is to leave a comment on your question asking that a higher-rep user add the desired tag.

Answer (score 3):

Simply flag your post for mod attention and indicate which tag you think the post should have.

The rep requirement is only 150 to create a new tag, and 15 to flag.

Comment: This is fine if the question is already asked. But in order to ask, you need at least one tag.